# Create chart based upon last row of table

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a graph which needs to be based upon the last row of a table

The table is updated daily, where we append the latest values to the bottom of the chart (and we archive monthly). I'd like to not have to update the graph each time I update the table

An example table is

```
Date                Car        Bike        Walk
2 days ago          33         22           14
1 day ago           30         12           18
Today               38         33           22
```

The date column actually has real dates, but I've set up this way to show intent.

I run manual reports which shows me the state of  each category (column) over time. However, for my dashboard, I only want to see the bottom row (which is also the most current).

This isn't valid, but something like

```
Chart data range: =MySheet!LastRow($A):LastRow($F)
```

This makes Excel throw an error

```
=MySheet!$A$MIN(ROW(rng))+ROWS(rng)-1:$F$MIN(ROW(rng))+ROWS(rng)-1
```

Is this possible in Excel?

Answer (score 0):

> > The table is updated daily, where we append the latest values to the bottom of the chart

If you sorted your data in the opposite order (most recent date at the top) then you'd always know that today's data was on row one.

You could consider any of these approaches-

- Store the data in reverse order. Change the update process so you insert each day's numbers on a new line at the top of the list.
- Keep the data stored as they are now, but re-sort (descending) on the date field just before you refresh your chart, then re-sort back to the original order. This could be scripted in VBA pretty easily (you mention you are using Excel).
- I suspect you could use your existing data table as a data source for PowerQuery, and use PQ to pull out the final row using a "date=max(date)" type query, then use that as your chart data source.